# Problem loading data in repeatable without saving data in JSON format Laravel-Backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I'm using the repeatable, from Laravel-Backpack I can save the data into the two tables. However, I can not load these data when trying to edit a sale. It does not load the data in the form that were saved through the Repeatable.

Example:

When viewing the example of the demo through the link.
https://demo.backpackforelaravel.com/admin/dummy/create
It converts the data from the fields from the REPEATABLE to JSON, and saves in the database in a field called Extra.

Saved format in the extra field in the database:

```
{
 "simple": "[{\"text\":\"TesteTesteTesteTeste\",\"email\":\"admin@admin\",\"textarea\":\"teste\",\"number\":\"1\",\"float\":\"1\",\"number_with_prefix\":\"1\",\"number_with_suffix\":\"0\",\"text_with_both_prefix_and_suffix\":\"1\",\"password\":\"123\",\"radio\":\"1\",\"checkbox\":\"1\",\"hidden\":\"6318\"}]",
}
```

In my case I am saving the data in different tables without using JSON.

```
//My Model
class Sales extends Model

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'user_id' => 'integer',
        'date_purchase' => 'date',
        'client_id' => 'integer',
    ];

    public function getProductsAttribute()
    {

        $objects = ItensProducts::where('product_id', $this->id)->get();
        $array = [];

        if (!empty($objects)) {
            foreach ($objects  as $itens) {
                $obj = new stdClass();
                $obj->product_id = "" . $itens->product_id;
                $obj->quantity  = "" . $itens->quantity;

                $categoryProduct = CategoryProduct::where('product_id',  $itens->product_id)->get();

                  $arrayCategoryProduct = [];
                foreach ($categoryProduct  as $stItens) {
                    $arrayCategoryProduct[] = $stItens->name;
                }
                $obj->categories_product = $arrayCategoryProduct;

                $array[] = $obj;
            }
        }
        //Converts JSON to the example of the extra database field 
        $array_result = json_encode(\json_encode($array), JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_APOS);
        $array_result = str_replace(['\u0022', '\u0027'], ["\\\"", "\\'"], $array_result);

        return $array_result;
    }
```

My form:

```
//SalesCruController.php
protected function setupCreateOperation()
    {
        CRUD::addField([   // repeatable
            'name'  => 'products',
            'label' => 'Produtos(s)',
            'type'  => 'repeatable',
            'fields' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'product_id', 'type' => 'select2', 'label' => 'Produtos',
                    'attribute' => "name",
                    'model' => "App\Models\Product",
                    'entity' => 'products',
                    'placeholder' => "Selecione o Produto",
                    'wrapper'  => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-6'
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'category_id', 'type' => 'select2', 'label' => "Categoria",
                    'attribute' => "name",
                    'model' => "App\Models\CategoryProduct",
                    'entity' => 'categories',
                    'placeholder' => "Selecione uma Categoria",
                ],
                [
                    'name'  => 'quantity',
                    'label' => "Quantidade",
                    'type'  => 'text',
                ],
            ],
            // optional
            'new_item_label'  => 'Adicionar',
            'init_rows' => 1,
            'min_rows' => 1,
            'max_rows' => 3,

        ],);
    }
}
```

Method Store

```
public function store()
    {
        $item = $this->crud->create($this->crud->getRequest()->except(['save_action', '_token', '_method']));

        $products = json_decode($this->crud->getRequest()->input('products'));

        $this->validateRepeatableFields($categoryProduct);

        if (is_array($products)) {

            foreach ($products  as $itens) {

                $obj = new ItensProduct();
                $obj->sale_id =  $item->getKey();
                $obj->product_id = $itens->product_id;
                $obj->quantity  = $itens->quantity;
                $obj->save();

                $categoryProduct = json_decode($itens->categories);

                foreach ($categoryProduct  as $cItens) {
                    $objCat = new CategoryProduct();
                    $objCat->product_id = $obj->getKey();
                    $objCat->name = $cItens;
                    $objCat->save();
                }
            }
        } else {
            \Alert::add('warning', '<b>Preencha os campos de pelo menos um produto.</b>')->flash();
            return redirect('admin/sales/create');
        }
        \Alert::success(trans('backpack::crud.insert_success'))->flash();
        return redirect('admin/sales');
    }

function validateRepeatableFields($categoryProduct)
{
    foreach ($categoryProduct as $group) {
        Validator::make((array)$group, [
            'sale_id' => 'required',
            'product_id' => 'required',
            'quantity' => 'required',
        ], [
            "product_id.required" => "O campo Produto é obrigatório",
            "quantity.required" => "O campo quantidade é obrigatório",
        ])->validate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem of returning the fields to the Repeatable form.

I want to share the solution if someone needs it. The error occurred when I tried to put the data from the category_id field which is a vector in a json it has to return like this, as shown below.

{"product_id": "4", quantity: "3", "category_id": "[10, 4, 8, 8]"}

The vector would have to be inside a string, I was passing the fields but was not converting the whole vector to a string in the format that the repeatable expected. Then I conceded the IDs in a string and in the end I conceded with the cohets and used the substring to remove the last virgulation, as the code below shows.

In this way I was able to return the fields with the appropriate information that were saved in the database in the Repeatable form.

```php
     public function getProductsAttribute()
    {
        $objects = ItensProducts::where('product_id', $this->id)->get();
        $response = [];
    
        if (!empty($objects)) {
            foreach ($objects as $itens) {
    
                $categoryProduct = CategoryProduct::where('product_id', $itens->product_id)->get();
    
                $itensCatProd = '';
                foreach ($categoryProduct as $itensCatProd) {
                    $itensCatProd .= $itensCatProd->id . ',';
                };
    
                $response[] = [
                    'product_id' => $itens->product_id,
                    'category_id' => '[' . substr($itensCatProd, 0, -1) . ']',
                    'quantity' => $itens->quantity,
                ];
    
                return json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    }
```